# What is your favorite feature in one language/framework/API 

Tags: design-patterns, programming-languages, language-design

What do you think is awesomely designed in one language (C, C++, JAVA, Ruby) or framework (Hibernate, Rails, ....) ? I think every one of these as something that makes it special. Therefore I'm asking each an everyone of you, what feature or piece of design/code do you think is great in one language/framework/...

For instance : iPhone objective's C delegation pattern is awesome.

Comment: To anyone who has used C#'s delegates (and now lambdas), Objective-C's delegation pattern is utterly horrid. It astounds me how much code I have to write to do something as simple as pop up a yes/no dialog. With any luck, this stuff will all soon get wrapped in APIs based on code blocks.

Comment: Hi Marcelo. I must say I agree. For most case, it's true that it's demotival to write 50 lines of code to just size a label right, for instance. But on the other hand, 10% of the time your client or you want something really specific, therefore you're happy that you can customize it the way you want. Also, I must add that if you are involve into iPhone dev, you HAVE TO capitalize on what you've done. For instance I've externalized SQLITE apis, ActivityIndicator, ActionSheet etc ... that way I can do the conventionnal stuff with one line of code, thanks to my ad-hoc API.

Answer (score 4):

- Pattern matching, in any language that supports it. And it's really a showstopper for languages that do not provide any.
- List comprehensions - the same, essential when they're available, pain when there are none.
- Closures
- Built-in documentation support: docstrings in Lisp, CWEB, Javadoc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Up to this point, I have always found `LINQ` very fascinating and very helpful in C#.

But, after looking at the future of C# (5.0), I am really excited about the `async` pattern and the fact that it will make a lot of people's lives easier.

There are a lot of other features I love (given is a priority list):

- `async`
- `LINQ` (I realized how much easier it is to work with `LINQ` when I had to work on a 2.0 project for a short period of time)
- `Lambda expressions`
- Built-in `iterator` pattern
- Built-in `observable` pattern

Comment: I've never been into C#. But yes, iterator pattern is now a must-have for languages. It so basic it saves so much time and lines of codes.

Answer (score 0):

- Pattern-matching in the ML family of languages
- Implicit `this` in method bodies in OOP languages
- Closures in functional languages
- Coroutines in Lua and other languages